# running Python script (Tkinter) on Windows

Tags: python, tkinter, exe, compatibility

I coded a script to help a person running a little experiment.
To make it easy, I programmed a little GUI using Tkinter.

Everything works smoothly on my Ubuntu laptop, and she's very happy with it. The problem is: she only runs Windows on her PC. Is there a way to make the script work on Windows too (considering it uses graphical libraries from Tkinter?). I would be very happy if I could just pack everything into a .exe file that I could then send over by email.

Keep in mind that I have to do everything on my PC (where there is only Linux) and then she has to run it on hers, where there is only Windows. Any suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you will be happier in the long run if you help her install python on her machine.  The Windows installer is fairly straightforward and installs tcl/tk/tkinter (and IDLE) unless one uncheck the corresponding check box.  You can then email .py files, using .pyw for tkinter scripts.  Double clicking with run the file with the python installed.  Change the code? email corrected file.  Add another file?  Email it. ...

Comment: The simplest thing would be to have her install ActivePython from activestate. With that, she'll be able to use any code you write that uses the standard python libraries (including Tkinter).

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) or [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/).